# Firebase IOS idToken invalid `kid` Exception in backend while `verifyIdToken` in Gmail Auth

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, token

I'm using firebase for Android and IOS application. The Application has dedicated backend and verifies the Token issued by firebase after phone/email auth using `verifyIdToken` method. I'm verifying the token for new user registration. The concept is working fine for android application. When new user `Authenticates`, Registration API going to be called with Token issued by Firebase and I'm verifying that token using `Service Account`. However, For ios it fails with the exception that `kid` header is invalid. Here is the exception trace.

```
A key with ID "3494b1e786cdad092e423766bbe37f54ed87b22d" could not be found. 
{"exception":"[object] (Firebase\\Auth\\Token\\Exception\\UnknownKey(code: 0): 
A key with ID \"3494b1e786cdad092e423766bbe37f54ed87b22d\" could not be found.
at /home/fgx3uhiothty/public_html/vendor/kreait/firebase-tokens/src/Verifier.php:132)
```

In Firebase Auth Documentation, there is clearly stated that

> kid   Key ID  Must correspond to one of the public keys listed at https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

When I checked key `3494b1e786cdad092e423766bbe37f54ed87b22d` with the google's public key after decoding token, I didn't find the `kid` matching. However, the token from ios device is issued by firebase itself after successful auth. So how is it possible having different `kid` header in ios token?

I'm using `kreait/firebase-tokens-php` library for accessing service account API from backend.

Comment: Thank you for writing this up and sharing it here - the issue was reported to me just a few times in the past couple of weeks, but often enough to reduce the likeability of some kind of misconfiguration. As I don't have the means to test/reproduce this myself, perhaps @frank-van-puffelen has some insight or ideas on the topic? My assumption so far was that the public keys got rotated after the issuance of the ID token, but I thought this to be really, really rare.

Comment: Oh God, You got it, The public keys are wrong, please not the `kid` header of the android token is correct. it happens to me with ios. This kind of bug affects the deployed system, I loose around 2k users. When I checked backend dashboard there is only 6.7k registered user and on firebase auth, the count is 8.4k. means so many users authenticated but can't be able to complete registration because of token verification error.

Comment: solved, `Firebase Docs` is not correct. LOL

Comment: @Kiran Maniya. How did you solve? How can be changed the firebase docs? You mean, google public key url is incorrect?
It has to be like this? `https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/my_firebase_service_account`

Comment: @devcrazy Detailed answer below, still won't get solved, feel free to reach me.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you are using a Google idToken, not a firebase idToken.
How did you get your idToken?
You can get idToken via this api:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken

Signin Callback function maybe like following.

```
var signInCb = function(authResult) {
    var uid = authResult.user.uid;
    authResult.user.getIdToken()
        .then( idToken => {
            // You can do some things with idToken here
                ....
        })
}
```

Comment: in the case of ios, it the firebase auth callback returns google it token.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, The behavior in ios devices are not identical to android because of firebase implementation. in ios, firebase redirects the user to the safari browser for email login and then returns flow to the app and it's not exactly same as android behavior.

I just worked around and decoded the firebase token. `aud`,`iss` and 'kid' header was not matching but was looking like a google's auth token issued from `web` hence I looked into [Web Sign-in Backend Auth Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) from google and found a clue. I found a `kid` header of `ios firebase token` here in [JWK](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) and [PEM](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs). Well, i have to use the [`Google API Client Library`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) and verified the token successfully.

In this case, for IOS device, the method `verifyIdToken()` of `Firebase Admin SDK` given in [Firebase Admin SDK Official Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) won't be worked at all. I think Firebase should update their docs. after several attempts of reaching them out could not solve the problem, instead, they just pushed the tooltip like given below,

[image: Tooltip from firebase Docs]

I suggest, for ios `Gmail Auth` use the method given in [Web Backend Auth](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server) instead of using `verifyIdToken()` of `Firebase Admin SDK`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description.@Kiran Maniya
I've changed the KEYS_URL from "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com" to "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
And I can find the matched kid. But "aud" and "iss" claims are different from the firebase official doc. "iss" is "account.google.com", and "aud" is "...uuid-like-string..apps.googleusercontent.com". 
Is my firebase project misconfigured? Or the doc is wrong? Thank you

Comment: Looks like docs missed some important details on this. Your project configuration is fine.